# Inline tag editor has buggy animation

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, inline-tag-editor

I recently earned access to moderator tools (yay!) and noticed the "animation" that looks rather buggy when opening / closing the inline tag editor tool:

[image: buggy animation gif]

Specifically, I'm talking about:

1. the jumpy, glitchy expanding/collapsing of the tag editor
2. the three black stripes at the top of the edit tags view

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Related: [Loading animation on edit screen is stretched vertically and appears as vertical lines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314686/289905).

Comment: Can you better describe what issue you see? I don't see any issue here aside from what I expect is graphical artifacts from the compression of your gif.

Comment: I can repro in Edge. It's not consistent, but sometimes it's really obvious.

Comment: @TylerH See the related question. There’s supposed to be a three dot animation, but the three dots are stretched accross the entire width of the Tags input field.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh, I thought that was an intentional design, considering a lot of the changes we see made lately.

Comment: The point is the that there are no artifacts in the gif - it reflects the real UI perfectly @TylerH

Comment: @LinusGeffarth The artifacts I'm referring to are the cross/diamond shaped grid of green saturated pixels across the entire gif. If you see that on your monitor on the live site then you probably need a new monitor.

Comment: @TylerH oh indeed, these aren't on the real UI. I was talking about the more obvious ones such as the jumps and the black bars at the top.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, as someone coming into this with only the information provided in the question - those aren't more obvious ones.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland What?! There are jumps that make the animation look glitchy and more importantly there are 3 bold black bars at the top. How are these not obvious?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, Just opened the page on my home computer and it is a completely different story from what I see on my work one, I'm guessing you're getting the same image I can now see here but let me assure you, on my other computer it's a mess, the three dots would be the least of your worries! **EDIT - A little more testing reveals it shows fine in Chrome but a mess in IE. That's why it isn't obvious.**

Comment: It's just in IE or Edge. Others work.

Comment: I'm using Safari though @zixuan

Comment: I promise, Firefox does work with the latest version.

Comment: Reproed on Chromium Version 74.0.3729.169, Linux

Comment: @Will but I can't repro in IE6 ...

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Try to reproduce again