# Strange animation after clicking "Edit tags"

Tags: bug, design, inline-tag-editor

When clicking <kbd>Edit tags</kbd> to use the inline tag editor, I get this weird-looking animation:

[image: Animation-SO-DarkMode]

Also, reproduced on Meta/light-mode:

<sub>*(Rapid flicker warning)*</sub>

> [image: Animation-Meta.SO-LightMode]

It appears to be some sort of progress animation that got stretched and I guess that wasn't intended.

Browser: Chrome v88.0.4324.146 on Windows.

Comment: Cross site duplicate/related: [Loader issue with inline tag editing on Firefox browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358602/loader-issue-with-inline-tag-editing-on-firefox-browser)

Comment: It’s one of the regressions of [Inline tag editor has buggy animation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387052/4642212). I think the tag editor isn’t the only thing with a bug like this.

Comment: Agreed. Just one remark: I mostly just use Chrome and I've never experienced this until today. So, it looks like it's new on Chrome (could be caused by a browser update though).